# Please suggest the best way of rendering Partials

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a new development task , I am trying to do reports dashboard and my requirement is to 
I will have a form and I need to select values from form and depending upon user selection I need to display high charts in the same page and tabular view of my data in same page. So my form content is static and my Highcharts data and tabular contains dynamic data.

Steps I have done so far:

1. Login form and if credentials are valid Displays my mainform.aspx 
   My mainform.aspx contians form with a submit button

   ```
    <form id="StatsForm" name="StatsForm" action="../Stats/Index/" method="POST"
               enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken()%>
               <% Html.RenderPartial("OptionalFields"); %>
           </form>
   ```
2. On button click I am sending my form data to controller

                   //

   ```
               $(document).ready(function () {
                   $("#GetReport").click(function () {
                       $("form[name=StatsForm]").submit();

                   });
               });

               //]]>
           </script>
   ```
3. I am doing some repository functions from my form data in my controller action and I am adding form values to a model class.

   ```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
      {
         var manufacturerId = Convert.ToInt32(form["manufacturerId"]);
       var reportId = Convert.ToInt32(form["reportId"]);
       var categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(form["categoryId"]);
       var retailerId = Convert.ToInt32(form["retailerId"]);
       var countryId = Convert.ToInt32(form["countryId"]);
       var regionId = Convert.ToInt32(form["regionId"]);
       var manufacturerWidgetId = (form["ManufacturerWidgetId"]);
       var startDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
       var endDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["StartDate"]))
       {

           startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(form["StartDate"]);
       }
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(form["EndDate"]))
       {
           endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(form["EndDate"]);
       }

       var reportName = _reportRepository.GetReport(reportId);


       var stats = new Stats
                       {
                           ManufacturerId = manufacturerId,
                           CountryId = countryId,
                           ReportName = reportName.ToString(),
                           StartDate = startDate,
                           EndDate = endDate
                           };
   ```
4. Now I am struck, I did below steps not sure if I am right. I thought because my mainform.aspx has to display dynamic partials I am trying to create partials foreach report and on selection of uservalue I am planning to inject corresponding partial in my mainform.aspx.

   for that I am doing : (continuation of my Action method)

   ```
        switch (reportName.Code)
       {
           case "INTER":
               return RedirectToAction("InterStats",
                                   new
                                   {
                                       manufacturerId = manufacturerId,
                                       countryId = countryId,
                                       startDate = "2013-01-01",
                                       endDate = "2013-01-31"

                                   });
               break;
           case "CUMLEADS":
               return RedirectToAction("ParametersCumLeads",
                                   new
                                   {
                                       manufacturerId = manufacturerId,
                                       countryId = countryId,
                                       categoryId = categoryId,
                                       startDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                       endDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                   });
               break;
           case "IMP":

               break;
       }
   ```

5.My partial view:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult InterStats(int manufacturerId, int countryId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {

        //Get all manufacturerwidgets for manufacturer
        var manufacturerWidget = _manufacturerWidgetsRepository.GetManufacturerWidgetByManufacturerAndCountry(manufacturerId, countryId);
        var interReport = new InterReport();
        var interRecordList = new List<InterRecord>(); // a list of my anonymous type without the relationships
        interReport.InterRecordList = new List<InterRecord>();
        var count = 1;
        foreach (var mw in manufacturerWidget)
        {
            var widgetName = mw.Description;

            //Get the product stats data
            var imps = _productStatsRepository.GetSumImpressionsProductStatsForManufacturerCountryDate(
                mw.Id, countryId, startDate, endDate);


            var clicks = _productStatsRepository.GetSumClicksProductStatsForManufacturerCountryDate(
                mw.Id, countryId, startDate, endDate);

            float ctr = 0;
            if (imps != 0 && clicks != 0)
            {
                ctr = ((clicks / (float)imps) * 100);
            }



            //  Create the data for the report
            var interRecord = new InterRecord
            {
                WidgetName = widgetName,
                Impressions = imps,
                Interactions = clicks,
                Ctr = ctr,
                Count = count
            };


            interReport.InterRecordList.Add(interRecord);

            count++;
        }
        interReport.Counter = count;
        return Json(interReport, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

1. And I tried in my mainform.aspx to write a small ajax function to render partial data , but $("#GetReport").click(function () I am sending form back to controller dont know how it will again here ?

   ```
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       //<![CDATA[

       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#GetReport").click(function () {
               $.ajax({

                   url: "/Stats/InterStats/<%: Model.ManufacturerId %>/<%: Model.CountryId %>/<%: Model.StartDate %>/<%: Model.EndDate %>",
                   type: 'get',
                   success: function (data) {
                       <% Html.RenderPartial("InterStats"); %>
                   }
               });

               $("form[name=StatsForm]").submit();
           });
       });

       //]]>
   </script>
   ```

   So I ahve my partial views, my data ready and I am not able to display corresponding partial in my mianform.aspx .Please help how can I do this?

Comment: Show relevant code only. Explain what the issue is, what you expect to happen and whay you have tried to resolve it. Now you just dump all your code and say _"I don't see any data"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have written all the code to know is there anything wrong in my approach. And coming to my problem, because on submit button click I am sending my form back and how can I display partial view as well without clicking button twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({

    url: "/Stats/InterStats/<%: Model.ManufacturerId %>/<%: Model.CountryId %>/<%: Model.StartDate %>/<%: Model.EndDate %>",
    type: 'get',
    success: function (data) {
        <% Html.RenderPartial("InterStats"); %>
    }
});
```

Instead of this, you need some javascript in the `success` function to handle the response.  Probably something like:

```
    success: function (data) {
        $('#someDivId').html(data);
    }
```